# connect/pair gopro Hero 4 camera using python

Tags: python, gopro

I am trying to use the python library for the *GoPro API* and I am new to this. I searched everywhere online and all posts seem to assume your camera is already paired with the computer. How do I connect my GoPro camera to the computer (wifi, USB?) so I can start talking to it via the python API ? I started by executing the following commands:

```
from goprocam import GoProCamera
from goprocam import constants
gpCam = GoProCamera.GoPro()
```

I get an error on line three and I assume it's because the camera is not yet connected to he computer.

Comment: Please provide the error you are receiving.

Comment: The error message is too long. But this is a snippet of first 2 lines:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\goprocam-1.9.6-py3.6.egg\goprocam\GoProCamera.py", line 144, in whichCam
    response_raw = urllib.request.urlopen('http://' + self.ip_addr + '/gp/gpControl', timeout=5).read().decode('utf8')

Comment: You need to post the entire error, or at least post the last 10-20 lines. The last part of the error is usually where it explains what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok. so I think I know the root cause. When I enable wifi on my GoPro, it will only showup on my computer WIfi networks if I hit Pair on the GoPro. The pairing will keep waiting for me to enter some code on the app side for 3 minutes, which is not the case because I am using the laptop. So I tried connecting within the 3 minutes and the error doesn't show anymore, however it times out after 3 minutes. So I guess the question is, how do I connect my GoPro to my laptop over wifi without using the pairing option on the camera ?

Comment: Oh I see you're trying to pair. Connect the camera to your computer, and run gopro = GoProCamera.GoPro(constants.startpair)

Comment: ok. I tried the pairing. "constants.startpair" is not defined, but I found "constants.pair". I executed this command and this is what I got:

Comment: >>> GoProCamera.GoPro(constants.pair)
Waking up...
Waking up...
Error, camera not defined.
Make sure your GoPro camera is in pairing mode!
Go to settings > Wifi > PAIR > GoProApp to start pairing.
Then connect to it, the ssid name should be GOPRO-XXXX/GPXXXXX/GOPRO-BP-XXXX and the password is goprohero
Enter pairing code: 9927

Comment: File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>

Comment: I need more context, is there a full log? Before running GoProCamera.GoPro(constants.pair) connect to the GoPro WiFi.  I'll try to reproduce the bug, what is the output of python --version?

Comment: The python version is:Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. The log is too large. Is there a way to attach it to this post ?

Comment: I finally figured it out. The issue was with my work computer. It must have had a firewall that prevented the script from recognizing the camera. I tried it from a personal computer and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

developer of gopro-py-api here. You need to turn on WiFi on your GoPro Camera, to App mode/Smartphone mode not Remote mode, then connect your camera to your computer via WiFi. Then run the commands again.

Comment: I did that. I have a GoPro 4. I select Turn Wifi On then App Mode then it pops up with a pin number that I need to enter on the app side to pair and that pin will expire in 2.5 minutes then it turns off Wifi. I tried pairing it with my phone app so it that pin doesn't pop up anymore, which worked. I now can get past gpCam = GoProCamera.GoPro() but when i try gpCam.shutter(constants.start), I get the same error.